# Updating Child Component State Based on Successful Execution of Parent Component's Reducer Function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to update the `Child` component if the reducer function in `Parent` component runs successfully.

```
function reducer(state, action) {
  if (action.type === "something") {
    try {
      action.cb();
      return { ...state, updated: true };
    } catch (error) {
      action.cb(error)
    }
  }
}

function Parent() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer)

  return <Child dispatch={dispatch}></Child>
}
```

```
function Child({ dispatch }) {
  const [state, setState] = useState(false)

  function handleClick () {
    function cb(err) {
      if (!err) {
        setState(true)
      } 
    }
        
    dispatch({ type: "something", cb: cb });
  }

  return <button onClick={handleClick}>Click me</button>;
}
```

When I run the above code I get a warning:

> Warning: Cannot update a component (Child) while rendering a different
> component (Parent)

How can I update the `Child` component's state if there is no error in the `reducer` function?

Answer (score 1):

[Do Not Put Non-Serializable Values in State or Actions](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/#do-not-put-non-serializable-values-in-state-or-actions)

You can subscribe to the changes of the `updated` state in the child component and set its state.

There is no need to use `try/catch`, if the `updated` state is not updated correctly, it still stays `false` value.

```
import { useEffect, useReducer, useState } from 'react';

function reducer(state, action) {
  if (action.type === 'something') {
    return { ...state, updated: true };
  }
}

function Parent() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, { updated: false });

  return <Child dispatch={dispatch} updated={state.updated}></Child>;
}

function Child({ dispatch, updated }) {
  const [state, setState] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (updated) {
      setState(true);
    }
  }, [updated]);

  function handleClick() {
    dispatch({ type: 'something' });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click me</button>
      <p>child state: {JSON.stringify(state)}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  return <Parent />;
}

export default App;
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-biwqgv?file=src%2FApp.tsx)

See also:

- [Using state after dispatch has fired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58209336/using-state-after-dispatch-has-fired)
- [useReducer's dispatch should return a promise which resolves once its action has been delivered](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15344)
- [Warning: Cannot update a component X while rendering a different Y component To locate the bad setState() call inside Y,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70556785/warning-cannot-update-a-component-x-while-rendering-a-different-y-component-to)

Answer (score 0):

Reducers are to be considered pure functions... don't pass in functions and invoke them from within your reducer function. Issue the side-effects appropriately via the `useEffect` hook or in an event callback, e.g. like `handleClick`.

In this case, issue the side-effect in the `handleClick` callback, and if *that* is successful, dispatch the action to update your state.

```
function reducer(state, action) {
  if (action.type === "something") {
    return { ...state, updated: true };
  }
}

function Parent() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer);

  return <Child dispatch={dispatch} />;
}
```

```
function Child({ dispatch }) {
  const [state, setState] = useState(false);

  async function handleClick () {
    try {
      /* some asynchronous logic or code that can reject or throw error */

      // success
      setState(true);
      dispatch({ type: "something" });
    } catch(error) {
      // failure
    }
  }

  return <button onClick={handleClick}>Click me</button>;
}
```